# how to find bases for subspace span of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: matrices

I have searched the internet, but I found contradicting answers.

Must the number of bases be exactly 3 if the space is $\mathbb{R}^3$? What if there is 1 redundant vector in the span? Will the bases then be 2 now?

For example, for subspace span{(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)} in $\mathbb{R}^3$, am I right to say the bases can be {(1,2,3),(4,5,6)} or perhaps {(1,2,3), (7,8,9)}?

But wouldn't that mean there are 2 bases, must there be 3 bases in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: What do you mean by "number of bases"? Do you mean the minimal number of elements of a base?

Comment: @Max done, do check the question again, let me know if its clearer?

Comment: What do you mean by “redundant vector”?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos (7,8,9) is redundant because the other 2 vectors are linear combination of (7,8,9)

Comment: Actually, *none* of the other two vectors is a linear combination of $(7,8,9)$. The only linear combinations of $(7,8,9)$ are the vectors of the form $(7\lambda,8\lambda,9\lambda)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, they are. -1(1,2,3) + 2(4,5,6) = (7,8,9)

Comment: What you can deduce from that equality is that $(7,8,9)$ is a linear combination of the other two vectors, not that the other two vectors are linear combinations of $(7,8,9)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, right, my bad. so one of the vectors is redundant.

Comment: And if $(7,8,9)$ is a linear combination of $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$, then the set $\{(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)\}$ is not linearly independent, and therefore it is not a basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, so am I right to say, {(1,2,3), (4,5,6)} or {(1,2,3), (7,8,9)} or {(4,5,6), (7,8,9)} is a basis for subspace span{(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)} in R3?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you so much. I understood it now. At first, I thought that the number of bases are strictly similar to the dimension of the space.

Comment: I must say that I still don't know what is that thing to which you call “the number of bases”.

Comment: @user13727667 you might want to make a terminological distinction between a *basis* (plural *bases*), which is a maximal set of linear independent vectors, and *basis vectors*, which are elements of a given basis. The *number of bases* you are talking about sounds alot like *number of basis vectors within a given basis* to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take the set of vectors you wrote $\mathcal A= \Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 7\\8\\9\end{pmatrix}\Bigg\}$ we can observe that
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}1&4&7\\2&5&8\\3&6&9 \end{pmatrix}\sim\begin{pmatrix}1&4&7\\0&-3&-6\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\implies\text{ rk}(M)=2$$
and this shows that the three vectors are not linearly independent. They span a vector space of dimension $2$.
For example $\mathbb R^3\ni\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\notin \langle \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6 \end{pmatrix}\rangle$, so $\mathcal A$ is not a basis for $\mathbb R^3$.
An example of basis for $\mathbb R^3$ is
$$\mathcal C=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}=\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} \Bigg\}$$

For definition a set of vector $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis for a vector space $V[\mathbb K]$ if:
$(i)$ $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a system of generators of $V$;
$(ii)$ $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent vectors;